# Convertir fichero de audio .au en .mp3 con php

Tags: php, html

La idea fundamental es poder reproducir un fichero de audio con formato Au(.au) en una página web pero no lo puedo hacer porque la etiqueta de html no soporta ese tipo de formato, entonces tengo que convertirlo a mp3. En el backend de mi aplicación web tengo php así que quisiera saber como puedo convertir de Au a Mp3

Comment: Desconozco si existe algo para tal fin en PHP, no obstante te podrías apoyar en python por ejemplo para que hiciera la conversión, creando un Script python para la conversion y haciendo que este sea llamado desde PHP.

Comment: Tu web está en un servidor dedicado o VPS? Necesitas instalar FFMpeg y tener PHP configurado para ejecutar comandos, de preferencia, en background o, cuando menos, tareas programadas para buscar los nuevos archivos a convertir.